# What is this mysterious function address in Time Profiler?

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

A function shows up in my iPhone app with only address: 0x8007c318. It consumes considerable CPU time; so I'd like to know what it is and reduce its CPU consumption.

Its callers are mostly other unknown functions (see list). Of the few my functions calling it, I can't find the place such call can happen.

Anyone knows about what this mysterious function is? I'm running iOS5.1 on iPhone4

```
Running Time,Self,,Symbol Name
3332.0ms  100.0%,3332, ,0x8007c318
1050.0ms   31.5%,0, , __psynch_cvwait
496.0ms   14.8%,0, , 0x80079b83
427.0ms   12.8%,0, , 0x80021621
209.0ms    6.2%,0, , 0x801d9363
205.0ms    6.1%,0, , 0x80020fe7
198.0ms    5.9%,0, , mach_msg_trap
141.0ms    4.2%,0, , 0x800761d7
140.0ms    4.2%,0, , 0x8000f211
139.0ms    4.1%,0, , kevent
50.0ms    1.5%,0, , 0x8000f487
48.0ms    1.4%,0, , 0x80079533
```

Comment: Sounds like private frameworks or ObjC runtime stuff.

Comment: But even private framework should have symbols

Comment: Not entirely true, you can strip those symbols so that people can't see them so easily, you should actually do this for your release builds. For example, open the Xcode Organizer and look at some crash logs of your device, you'll probably see just a lot of addresses when it comes to the application's functions.